# MySQL hanged after LoadTest. Error 2002 - The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-2002

I had a project running on my server. I ran "LoadTest" and it hanged my MySQL server. Now I cannot connect to the server via UI. If I try restart via command line, then also getting error "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/path/mysql/mysqld.sock'.

I checked the path, it is correct and mysqld.sock also exist.

What should I do to make server running up again?  Please help me!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

MySql itself shouldn't be "hanging" - I'm not sure exactly what you did, or what the root cause is.

Q: Have you recycled the OS?  Did everything come up after recycle?

Q: What *IS* the OS?  Windows?  Linux?  What version?

Q: Have you checked the MySql and OS event logs for errors?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu.. Apache is working but only issue connecting MySQL localhost. I didn't enabled MySQL error logs.. so not able to find any errors..

Comment: 1) reboot and see if you can use "mysql" from the command line after reboot.  Please report back the results.  2) After rebooting, check /var/log/syslog for any My-Sql related errors  3) Regardless of whether or not you "enabled MySQL error logs" (and you should!), please check for /var/log/mysqld.log.  Report back what you find.

Comment: Thanks for help, pls find my answer : (1) The issue is I am not able to restart/start/stop mysql... it says "could not connect to server through socket '/path/mysql/mysqld.sock'. (2) Cannot find anything in /var/log/syslog yet. It has entry 1 hour before it got hanged.  (3) cannot find /var/log/mysqld.log file..  I am still analyzing server.. I think I need to wait sometime coz "too many connection started via loadtest" :(